# How to filter objects for django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to integrate [this](http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum1.html) simple django forum to an existing project.

In admin.py I have

```
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["title", "forum", "creator", "created"]
    list_filter = ["forum"]
...
```

The problem is that since there are +100K users, when I try to add a topic from admin panel, browser just hangs or becomes so slow, because it needs to load all the +100K users in `creator` field.

So I am wondering how to filter users in the form so that admin.py loads only superusers in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default form for the `TopicAdmin` and set a required queryset for the `creator` field:

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TopicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['creator'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)

class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TopicForm
    ...
```

But may be the [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) attribute of the `ModelAdmin` is the better option for you?

```
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    raw_id_fields = ['creator']
```

Comment: Filtering `creator` in __init__ was still slow persumably because the query still run,  but using raw_id_field did the job pretty well. Many thansk

Comment: I suppose that the problem not in the sql query but in the rendering/loading of 100K users.

Comment: Right, that's a tough job for browser.